# Как подсоединить справочник к сгруппированному DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

Есть сгруппированный фрейм

```
df6_1.groupby(['tr_type'])['amount'].max().sort_values(ascending = False).tail()


tr_type
6000    79280.83
8100    64682.37
1010    28803.87
2020     2245.92
4110     2245.92
Name: amount, dtype: float64
```

Eсть ли возможность подсоединить к нему справочник?

Что-то похожее:

```
.merge(df0, how='inner', left_on = 'tr_type', right_on = 'tr_type')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
res = res_df6.reset_index(name='Val').merge(df0, on='tr_type')
```

Comment: Спасибо  большое)